# Identifying tomcat startup completion from powershell

Tags: powershell, logfile, file-read

I have set of powershell scripts that manage startup process of a Windows server.  At some point, the powershell starts the tomcat server.  The tomcat is set up as a windows service and is started by using `net start`. Once the command return the tomcat is started, but not the application. The application takes another 15-30 minutes to start.

The definitive way to say that it's started is to check log file and see line "Server startup successful".  Note that this line may already be present in the file due to an earlier restart.

Another way (which is less reliable) is to send https request to localhost on the corresponding port number and check the actual content of the response.  There are separate issues associated with it, specifically HTTP cert error when accessing localhost and also the fact that in some cases even the correct response doesn't guarantee that the application is fully started.

How can I from the powershell determine that the application has fully started - before continuing with the next task?

Comment: Is the line that says "Server startup successful" timestamped in any way?  One way would be to search the log for that line and parse the timestamp to see if it's after the startup time of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to compare the content of the log file before and after start with a do-until loop and continue your script once the string is found:

```
$beforestart = Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\tomcat.log
net start ...

do
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    $afterstart = Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\tomcat.log
    $compare = Compare-Object $beforestart $afterstart
}
until ($compare -match 'Server startup successful')
```

Comment: The log files can grow to several gig. I don't think it's feasible to do such comparison every few seconds or even every few minutes

Answer (score 0):

As automatedorder commented, if the lines have a timestamp those could be used to determine the order of the entries.

Another option you could consider is `Select-String` Each match will be accompanied by a line number. Since you haven't provided sample log data, I'll make some up. You said "Server startup successful" is for the application starting. I've added "Service start successful" in this example as the entry for the service.

Fake sample log I added two entries each to simulate previous service/application starts.

```
$logfile = 'c:\temp\apache-test.log'

@'
Service start successful
some other logging
more logging
not important
Server startup successful
Service start successful
some other logging
more logging
not important
Server startup successful
'@ | Out-File $logfile -Encoding utf8
```

Here we will take the last match for each activity. They will be assigned to each respective variable.

```
$service,$application = 'Service start successful','Server startup successful' | foreach {
    Select-String -Path $logfile -Pattern $_ | select -Last 1
}
```

Contents of each variable

```
$service

C:\temp\apache-test.log:6:Service start successful


$application

C:\temp\apache-test.log:10:Server startup successful
```

Now we simply check that the application linenumber is larger than the service linenumber to confirm the application is started.

```
if($application.linenumber -gt $service.linenumber){"Application started successfully"}
```

You can simulate a test where the log is new and only contains a service start message.

```
@'
Service start successful
some other logging
more logging
not important
'@ | Out-File $logfile -Encoding utf8

$service,$application = 'Service start successful','Server startup successful' | foreach {
    Select-String -Path $logfile -Pattern $_ | select -Last 1
}

if($application.linenumber -gt $service.linenumber){"Application started successfully"}
```

Unless you're running in strict mode, you won't get any errors and of course the message "Application started successfully" (or whatever you run after confirmation) won't be executed.

Edit:

As far as speed, `Select-String` will be much faster on larger files than `Get-Content`. You will need to do testing in your environment to see how fast it runs. One option you have if you to shrink the size of the text you're testing is to use the `-Tail` parameter of `Get-Content`. You could, for example, grab just the last 100 lines of the log file and test against that.

```
$tempfile = New-TemporaryFile
Get-Content -Tail 100 $logfile | Out-File $tempfile -Encoding utf8

$service,$application = 'Service start successful','Server startup successful' | foreach {
     Select-String -path $tempfile -Pattern $_ | select -Last 1
}

if($application.linenumber -gt $service.linenumber){"Application started successfully"}
```

Comment: How quick is the check? The log files can be several gig long.

Comment: Test these out.